# i want to enter text in textbox by dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html

i have a dropdown, which have a list of items.if i select aa item in dropdown it's corresponding value should populate in the text box which is below the dropdown.
i'm trying to think this way

dropdown id= "StandardComment"
textarea id = areaComments

areaComments.text = StandardComment.selectedindex.value

Please help

Comment: for example- if i select "shipping" from dropdown, it should give me amount for the shipping in the text Area. hope i have made it clear

Comment: Are you using a framework, such as jQuery or Prototype? Or do you want straight JS?

Answer (score 0):

```
function transfereValue(){
ob = document.getElementById('StandardComment');
val = ob.value
document.getElementById('areaComments').value = val
}
```

in your dropdown

```
<select id="StandardComment" onchange="transfereValue()">
<option value="blahh">Blah</option>
<option value="blahh2">Blah2</option>
<option value="blahh3">Blah3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this jsfiddle I've created? It'll automactially insert the values you input, then select into the text-box.

http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/u9cSr/